# Is it possible to change the company behind a developer account?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

A few years ago I created a company to start an app project. I released the series of apps but things did not work very well. The apps did not generate any significant revenue and I gradually abandoned the project. The company did still exist, but my accountant charged me an annoyingly big amount of money to just keep the company, which had nearly no income and nearly not expenses, alive.

After a while, and after a big bill from the accountant, I started the process of shutting down the company to avoid the expenses. This process just managed to be completed when something happened...

On a day with some extra time on my hands I did some small changes to the apps on the account registered to the deleted company, and in the following weeks things started really rolling. Now the apps are making a lot of money...

Everything is functioning properly, and money is paid out to my personal bank account. I did not think of this as a problem until my accountant responsible for doing the accounting for my personal company, doing my taxes etc, notified me that I could not write off expenses for some ads that I had run to get more downloads of the now revived apps.

After thinking about all of this for a while I am now very worried that I am in big problems. What will happen if I tell Apple that the company behind my app-account is no longer active? Will they shut down the account and all my apps?

Can I change the company behind the developer account if I start a new company?

I am unable to create a new account and transfer my apps as all the apps uses Auto-Renewable Subscriptions which for some reason cannot be included when transferring an app between accounts. The extremely bad timing of shutting down the seemingly "dead" company is really torturing me. Now I am afraid Apple will suddenly shut down my account and stop all payments as the company no longer exists.

Can someone please help me regain some faith that I am not in deep trouble? I am very nervous about this.

I am worried I have made a big mistake.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be anything to worry about.

> What will happen if I tell Apple that the company behind my app-account is no longer active? Will they shut down the account and all my apps?

Not exactly. Best recourse in this scenario is to get in touch with the Apple developer support and discuss your case. Apple Developer support can be reached over Phone or email. The concerned personnel will be able to study your scenario and offer you applicable advise. They can direct you with moving over your apps to a different company.

Get started by visiting [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) website, login with your registered Apple ID, and select the applicable case.

[image]

> Can I change the company behind the developer account if I start a new company?

Yes. iTunes Connect does allow transferring apps to another developer account. Relevant documentation can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f). You should be also be able to discuss this query with you developer support representative.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I am worried they will tell me to transfer my apps to a new account. But as mentioned in the original post my apps can not be transferred as they all include Auto-Renewable Subscriptions which Apple states themselves prevents an app from being able to be transferred.